# Rename custom attribute from sales/quote in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to rename a custom attribute in Magento, the following code adds the attribute I just need the equivalent to remove using the Magento installer scripts:

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "is_school",  array(
    "type"     => "int",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Organisation Type?",
    "input"    => "int",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => false,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""
));

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/quote'), 'is_school', 'int(11)');
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales/order'), 'is_school', 'int(11)');

// need code to rename these two column above from is_school to 'org_type'

$installer->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$installer->getConnection()
->changeColumn($tableName, $oldColumnName, $newColumnName,$definition);
```

Where

```
`changeColumn` method is used to modify and rename existing column in the table. It has such parameters:

$tableName - the table name that should be modified
$oldColumnName- the old name of the column, that should be renamed and modified
$newColumnName- a new name of the column
$definition - a new definition of the column (INT(10), DECIMAL(12,4), etc)
```

For more information

- `addColumn()` method adds new column to exiting table. It has such parameters:

  - `$tableName` - the table name that should be modified
  - `$columnName`- the name of the column, that should be added
  - `$definition` - definition of the column (`INT(10)`, `DECIMAL(12,4)`, etc)
- `addConstraint()` method creates a new constraint foreign key. It has such parameters

  - `$fkName` - the foreing key name, should be unique per database, if you don't specify `FK_` prefix, it will be added automaticaly
  - `$tableName` - the table name for adding a foreign key
  - `$columnName` - the column name that should be refered to another table, if you have complex foreign key, use comma to specify more than one column
  - `$refTableName` - the foreign table name, wich will be handled
  - `$refColumnName` - the column name(s) in the foreign table
  - `$onDelete` - action on row removing in the foreign table. Can be empty string (do nothing), `cascade`, `set null`. This field is optional, and if it is not specified, `cascade` value will be used.
  - `$onUpdate` action on row key updating in the foreign table. Can be empty string (do nothing), `cascade`, `set null`. This field is optional, and if it is not specified, `cascade` value will be used.
  - `$purge` - a flag for enabling cleaning of the rows after foreign key adding (e.g. remove the recodrs that are not referenced)
- `addKey()` method is used for adding of indexes to a table. It has such parameters:

  - `$tableName` - the table name where the index should be added
  - `$indexName` - the index name
  - `$fields` - column name(s) used in the index
  - `$indexType` - type of the index. Possible values are: `index`, `unique`, `primary`, `fulltext`. This parameter is optional, so the default value is `index`
- `dropColumn()` method is used for removing of columns from the existing table. It has such parameters:

  - `$tableName` - the table name that should be modified
  - `$columnName`- the name of the column, that should removed
- `dropForeignKey()` method is used for removing of foreing keys. It has such parameters:

  - `$tableName` - the table name for removing a foreign key
  - `$fkName` - the foreing key name
- `dropKey()` method is used for removing of the table indexes. It has such parameters:

  - `$tableName` - the table name where the index should be removed
  - `$keyName` - the index name
- `modifyColumn` method is used to modify existing column in the table. It has such parameters:

  - `$tableName` - the table name that should be modified
  - `$columnName`- the name of the column, that should be renamed
  - `$definition` - a new definition of the column (`INT(10)`, `DECIMAL(12,4)`, etc)
- `changeColumn` method is used to modify and rename existing column in the table. It has such parameters:

  - `$tableName` - the table name that should be modified
  - `$oldColumnName`- the old name of the column, that should be renamed and modified
  - `$newColumnName`- a new name of the column
  - `$definition` - a new definition of the column (`INT(10)`, `DECIMAL(12,4)`, etc)
- `changeTableEngine` method is used to change table engine, from MyISAM to InnoDB for instance. It has such parameters:

  - `$tableName` - the table name
  - `$engine` - new engine name (`MEMORY`, `MyISAM`, `InnoDB`, etc)

Let me know if you have any query